# What is needed to install OpenGl?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I set up OpenGl with DevC++ following a tutorial and everything works. I've looked into the main OpenGl project page (https://www.opengl.org/) but I can't find an official repository where I can download the packages that I need (I've found .zip but I can't understand the correct files that I need :(). I have seen many tutorials but they use unofficial repositories and they install packages in so many different ways even for the same IDE! :(. Is there an official repository? What files do I need? Is there a unique way to install OpenGL and if not could you tell me the most important steps of the installation ?

Comment: OpenGL is part of the firmware in your video card.

Comment: OpenGL comes with your graphics drivers. You can use it by itself, but setting up a window and loading extension functions manually becomes a pain, so people use third-party libraries like GLEW and GLFW to help automate some of it.

Comment: tell me if I have understood. The libraries that I set up help my IDE to find and work with OpenGl? Is this correct?

Comment: Probably. I don't know what the steps you're doing are, so I can't tell you exactly.

Comment: I've add this files: A header file: "gl.h" for core OpenGL, "glu.h" for GLU, and "glut.h" (or "freeglut.h") for GLUT, typically kept under "include\GL" directory.
A static library: for example, in Win32, "libopengl32.a" for core OpenGL, "libglu32.a" for GLU, "libglut32.a" (or "libfreeglut.a" or "glut32.lib") for GLUT, typically kept under "lib" directory.
An optional shared library: for example, "glut32.dll" (for "freeglut.dll") for GLUT under Win32, typically kept under "bin" or "c:\windows\system32".

Comment: You will need to download glut if you want to use it. gl and glu should be available on your machine already.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a unique way to install OpenGL and if not could you tell me the most important steps of the installation?

Install drivers for your graphics card with OpenGL support. Done!

---

OpenGL is different than Direct3D or Mantle (or, soon to come, Vulkan): Back in 1996 OpenGL-1.1 was included into the Windows 32 bit platform ABI (Application Binary Interface). That means that for every Windows version after "Windows 95B" and "Windows NT 4.0" programs are assured for OpenGL-1.1 to be available.

Being part of the platform ABI has the nice side effect and consequence, that everything that's required for OpenGL development **must** be included in every compiler package that targets the Windows 32 bit (and by heritage the 64 bit) platform.

However the ABI covers only OpenGL-1.1. For everything that comes after the so called "extension mechanism" is provided. By using the extension mechanism programs can determine at runtime, which OpenGL capabilities (beyond v1.1) are available and load them. No extra libraries or SDKs are required for this!

Yet, since the process of enumerating available OpenGL capabilities and loading them is so tedious, a number of helper libraries exists that alleviate one from this annoying task.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have OpenGL in your system as a part of your graphic card... You can see how to have a project running for different OS by taking a look at the OpenGL superbible:

https://sgar91.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/opengl-superbible-comprehensive-tutorial-and-reference-5th-edition-2010.pdf

Page 48 starts to talk about how to have a program running with OpenGL